# Python: Selenium stop running when window is in background or not shown on display

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have a script which manages a bunch of selenium instances that use UndetectedChromedriver and have a single tab open each one on a different website.
I have to wait for an external output and than i run a series of functions with threads/ThreadPoolExecutor to achieve concurrency

Everything work fine except that when a window is not on display it will freeze until it isn't shown on desktop and it won't even raise a timeout exception.
I found that this can be avoided by pressing the "win" key which shows all apps that i have open and this make the script run flawlessly but for obvious reasons it is not a good solution.

I tried adding a bunch of options as suggested some SO posts:

```
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/profiles/{self.name}/")
    options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory=profile')
    options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
    options.add_argument('--ash-no-nudges')
    options.add_argument('--disable-features=Translate')

    # added to fix this issue (didn't work)
    options.add_argument('--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows')
    options.add_argument('--disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion')
    options.add_argument('--disable-renderer-backgrounding')

    driver = Chrome(
    options=options,
    version_main=120,
    driver_executable_path='/home/hypnos/.local/share/undetected_chromedriver/undetected_chromedriver'
    )
```

I also read about docker-selenium and selenium-grid but i don't know how this will behave in terms of performances and would prefer to avoid using them.